UV Edit Material Warp
I've been trying to make a near seamless can texture by using a matierial image texture and uv wrapping it in the uv edit tab, so far I can't find a solution to the texture warping inwards displayed via the image below.
Do you know the solution to this problem? or why this happens?

My edge seam (idk if this may be apart of the problem?)


Normally you'd put the edge seam at the back of the tin so that it can't be seen when rendered. You have it in full view in the worst possible position!

You do not show it in the screenshots, but is there a chance you have a Subdivision Surface or any other modifier on the object? Because in the lower image in Edit Mode I cannot see the distortion. So I would guess it has to do with a modifier that is disabled in Edit Mode.

Yeah, @GordonBrinkmann might be onto it, there are also different options in the SS mod for how to deal with UVs that can probably fix it as well. Under Advanced > UV Smooth.

I could not find anyone who had a solution and no one one here had a solution for me, thankfully I figured out the problem myself by looking at can models that didn't have the same problem.
To solve the warping at the seam, all you need to do is add more loop cuts to the longer faces, idk why this happens, I just know this fixed my issue with the seam warping inwards.

End Result:

